# decimal numbers are stored as very long decimals instead of original values

Tags: sqlite

I would like to store numeric values to sqlite db, like 1; 1.1; 2.123; etc.
But 1.1 is stored in db as 1.1000000000000000888,
1.2 is stored in db as 1.1999999999999999556,
etc.

Why it is not simply stored as 1.1, or 1.2?

But for example 21.375 is stored as 21.375; 21.5 is stored as 21.5, strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because SQLite [has no decimal numbers](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes); what you get is a floating-point number.

You can round the numbers after you have read them from the database.
Alternatively, store them as scaled integers (2123 = 2.123 * 1000), or as strings.